# UNION without comparing one of the columns

Tags: sql, oracle, union

I have two queries

```
select A, B, C, D from T1, T2

select A, B, C, D from T2, T3
```

I want to do a UNION of the two queries (no duplicates) but not comparing column D, that is if columns A B and C are the same then they are considered duplicates regardless of D. I do not want to select from joined tables T1, T2, and T3. Is this possible on a single statement?
(this is Oracle)

Comment: But, do you want to show value of D?

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result.

Comment: if 2 rows A,B,C same, what value of D you need ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `UNION` and `GROUP BY` to do this, like following;)

```
select A, B, C
from(
    select A, B, C, D from T1, T2
    union
    select A, B, C, D from T2, T3
)t
group by A, B, C
```

And you have to specify which `D` value do you want to get when `A, B, C` are the same, here I assume you get max(D), like this;

```
select A, B, C, max(D) as D
from(
    select A, B, C, D from T1, T2
    union
    select A, B, C, D from T2, T3
)t
group by A, B, C
```

No matter which value you want to reserve, when you use `group by` in oracle, you only can select columns which appear in `group by` or some other columns with aggregation functions.